# How to write clean code in this multithread situation?

Tags: c#, multithreading

This code works good but looking awful. How to write beautiful code in this situatuion?

You can looking it in playground: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GUZni0

Or code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    static object valueLocker = new Object();
    static List<int> uidList;
    static int takeuid = -1;
    static int countThreads = 0;
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (;;) { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        uidList = new List<int>();
        uidList.Add(0);
        uidList.Add(1);
        uidList.Add(2);
        uidList.Add(3);
        uidList.Add(4);
        countThreads = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(TakeUidThread);
            thread.Start();
        }
```

Main thread check every 0.5 sec when threads finished and get new uidList

```
        while (countThreads < 10)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All threads finished");

        }
    }

    public static void TakeUidThread() 
    {
        var localuid = -1;

            while (localuid < uidList.Count)
            {
                // thread takes free uid
                lock (valueLocker)
                {
                    takeuid++;
                    localuid = takeuid;
                }

                if (localuid < uidList.Count && localuid != -1)
                {
                    DoSomeJob(uidList[localuid]);
                }

            }
```

Thread inc countThreads at end

```
            lock (valueLocker)
            {
                countThreads++;
            }
    }
    private static void DoSomeJob(int uid)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What would you like to clean? It isn't fully clear

Comment: I thought my code was too bad and nobody doing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try *PLinq* (*Parallel* Linq) for this, and get rid of `lock`s, `Thread`s etc.

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  uidList
    .AsParallel()
    //.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
    //.AsOrdered()
    .ForAll(item => DoSomeJob(item));
```

Comment: Nice to know! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad way to use threads. A thread is a really heavy thing to start and considered a good solution only when it performs some hardcore calculations.  When working in a multi-threaded environment, you need to choose between two targets:

- *you do it for performance*: you actually do a lot of CPU work, which includes some algorithmic complexity which can't be lowered other ways. It can be from simple sorting on big collections to very complex parsing algorithms, such as natural language processing and so on.
- *you do it for Input/Output (I/O)*: service a lot of clients, most of the time you wait for result from other endpoints such as SQL server, hard drive, network interfaces or some other system components.

For performance you do this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(uidList, DoSomeJob);
```

this will create heavy-weight `Thread`s and pretty much use your entire CPU capabilities at some point in time.

For I/O you do this:

```
private async Task DoSomeJob(int uid){ ... }

await Task.WhenAll(uidList.Select(DoSomeJob));
```

This will require `async` style development, but `Task` is a very light-weight object and you will rarely see your CPU go to even 1% because it is expected that most of the time your task is doing nothing but wait for something to happen, and then something else, and then all of them... and so on.